# Gulp - Cannot find module 'gulp-rename'

Tags: javascript, sass, gulp

I trying to set up Gulp to compile a SCSS file and also rename the SCSS file in the process - so for example:

I want **SCSS/original.scss** to be saved as **CSS/new.css**

This is on a Windows 10 VM

I have installed Gulp, installed gulp-sass which all worked just fine

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');

gulp.task('compile-new-main', function(){
 return gulp.src('scss/new-main.scss')
  .pipe(sass()) // Using gulp-sass
  .pipe(gulp.dest('css'))
 });
```

Running the above gulp task works just fine but when I try and install gulp-rename as the following the task breaks:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var rename = require("gulp-rename");

gulp.task('compile-new-main', function(){
 return gulp.src('scss/new-main.scss')
  .pipe(sass()) // Using gulp-sass
  .pipe(rename("styles.css"))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('css'))
 });
```

I initially tried just installing gulp rename with this command

```
npm install gulp-rename
```

The same as I did for gulp-sass which seemed to work just fine as before, clearly not but I'm not sure how or why.

I've done some Googling and tried installing it globally which again seemed to install fine

```
npm install gulp-rename -g
```

And I also saw some recommendations of saving gulp-rename as a dev-dependancy so I tried

```
npm install gulp-rename --save-dev
```

Again no errors in installing.

When I try and run my gulp task this is the error message I get:

> Error: Cannot find module 'gulp-rename'
>       at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
>       at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
>       at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
>       at Object. (C:\Projects\VAT-Expert\gulpfile.js:3:14)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)

I can't get my head around what I've done wrong here, think I've added all of the relevant information here - very much appreciate any guidance or advice on what I could try on this one!

N

Comment: Is there a `gulp-rename` within your `node_modules` directory?

Comment: @Philipp Ahh no there isn't - clearly it hasn't installed ... I'll try it all again and try and figure out why it hasn't installed and / or how to get it installed ...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

First, make sure that gulp-rename is listed in your `package.json` under `dependencies` or `devDependencies`. Then run:

```
npm uninstall -g gulp
npm install -g gulp
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
```

Then check again.

Answer (score 3):

install the `gulp-rename` package from cli:

```
npm install --save-dev gulp-rename
```

then import the package from node_modules

```
const rename = require("gulp-rename");
```

use it before compiling

**Example:**

```
const miniCSS = () => {
    return gulp.src('./css/*.css')
    .pipe(rename('style.min.css'))
    .pipe(uglifycss({
        "uglyComments": true
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is already answered, but I'm posting this as another solution for a PHP project.

1. `$ npm install gulp-rename` would work just fine and install the package but still got the `Cannot find module 'gulp-rename'` error.
2. I could find the package in `node_modules` if I went back one directory further back from my root project folder. I did not have a `package.json` file in this directory for whatever reason.
3. Doing `$ which gulp-rename` would not display anything, but I know it was already installed in `node_modules`.

To fix it under these conditions, I did:

```js
var rename = require('../node_modules/gulp-rename/index.js');
```