# Error: Cannot find module 'gulp-uglify/minifier'

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp

**Environment**

Ubuntu 17.04

**Steps**

Installed Node via [official instructions](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions):

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Installed gulp via [official instructions](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md):

```
npm install --global gulp-cli
```

Which caused permission errors:

```
Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/lib/node_modules'
```

So followed relevant [official instructions](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions):

```
# Make a directory for global installations:
mkdir ~/.npm-global

# Configure npm to use the new directory path:
npm config set prefix '~/.npm-global'

# Open or create a ~/.profile file and add this line:
export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH

# Back on the command line, update your system variables:
source ~/.profile
```

Created a `package.json` file in my project folder with this content:

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
  },
  "dependencies": {}
}
```

Ran the following in my project folder:

```
npm install gulp --save-dev
npm install gulp-clean-css --save-dev
npm install gulp-concat --save-dev
npm install gulp-rename --save-dev
npm install gulp-sass --save-dev
npm install gulp-uglify --save-dev
npm install pump --save-dev
npm install uglify-js-harmony --save-dev
```

Which then populated the `package.json` file so it looked like:

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-clean-css": "^3.3.1",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
    "gulp-sass": "^3.1.0",
    "gulp-uglify": "^3.0.0",
    "pump": "^1.0.2",
    "uglify-js-harmony": "^2.7.7"
  },
  "dependencies": {}
}
```

Then:

```
npm install --global gulp-cli
```

The relevant task in `gulpfile.js` looks like this:

```
// BEGIN get gulp plugins
var gulp = require('gulp');
var pump = require('pump');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var uglifyjs = require('uglify-js-harmony'); 
var minifier = require('gulp-uglify/minifier');
var cleanCSS = require('gulp-clean-css');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
// END get gulp plugins

gulp.task('bundle_js', function () {
  // the same options as described above 
  var options = {
    preserveComments: 'license'
  };

  pump([
      gulp.src('scripts/*.js'),
      minifier(options, uglifyjs),
      concat('script_bundle.js'),
      gulp.dest('scripts_bundled')
    ]
  );
});
```

Running:

```
gulp bundle_js
```

Causes this error:

```
throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'gulp-uglify/minifier'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/me/Desktop/myGulpProject/gulpfile.js:6:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
```

**What I've Tried:**

I tried manually removing the `node_modules` folder in my project folder and then running:

```
npm install --save-dev
```

I also tried:

```
npm uninstall -g gulp
npm install -g gulp
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
```

From: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42090366/1063287

I then tried uninstalling and re-installing `node`, `npm` and `gulp`:

```
npm uninstall gulp -g

sudo apt-get remove nodejs
sudo apt-get remove npm
```

from:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/33947181/1063287

```
cd /usr/local/lib/
sudo rm -rf node_modules/

cd ~
rm -rf .npm
rm -rf .npm-global
rm -rf .npmrc
```

from:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/11178106/1063287

```
vim .profile // and commented out line added previously to address permission errors
```

And removed `node_modules` folder from my project folder.

And then re-installed as described above.

I still have the same error.

```
throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'gulp-uglify/minifier'
```

Comment: npm install gulp-uglify/minifier --save-dev

Comment: Prompted: `The authenticity of host 'github.com (192.30.255.112)' can't be established. RSA key fingerprint is SHA256:xxx.  Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?`.  I entered `yes` and got errors like `ERR! git clone`, `Permission denied (publickey)`, `fatal: Could not read from remote repository.`

Comment: Also: `Warning: Permanently added 'github.com,192.30.255.112' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.`

Comment: First you can create ssh key for git account for system where you want to clone your repo.Then Run your script file.

Comment: download the zip project from git then move it to your `node_modules` directory , install the module dependencies if you dont have them @user1063287

Comment: There's no `gulp-uglify/minifier` anymore, the package was updated https://github.com/terinjokes/gulp-uglify/releases